# How do I limit the results of an SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I want to limit the results of a query in MySQL. I want the query to search 5000 rows but return only 5 of the 50 that found. How is it possible to do this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty basic SQL stuff. Check out the LIMIT modifier. You want to do something like:

```
    SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 5
```

Comment: nop this is going to search only 5 rows in the table not all of them

Comment: +1 for quick and right, answer, just to add, you can also do LIMIT x,y to select rows from interval from x to y

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM ANYTABLE LIMIT 50;
```